# how to retrieve emails from gmail using imap in php?

Tags: php, email, imap

this is my code

```
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'email@example.com';
$password = 'password';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to `Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());`
```

I have copied this code form another website to test but i am getting this error!!

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in E:\xampp\htdocs\mail\index.php on line 42
>   Cannot connect to Gmail: Too many login failures
>   Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Unknown: Too many login failures (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: It means imap can't connect to your gmail account

Comment: Thanks for your comment but why is this happening even i am using correct email and password

Comment: even extension imap.dll is enabled in php.ini  and from gmail imap an pop is also enabled

Comment: try this $hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/pop3/ssl}INBOX';

Comment: Generate an App Specific Password.   Or use OAuth. Or turn on access for less secure apps.

Comment: _"Cannot connect to Gmail: Too many login failures "_ - that sounds like a temporary(?) block, based on the fact that you failed to login correctly too many times.